YOLOV8 PSCAL 2007
We've been working on training a YOLOv8 model for object detection using the PASCAL VOC 2007 dataset. The model has achieved an accuracy of around 80%, which seems promising given the dataset's complexity. Could you provide some insights on whether this accuracy level is considered good for this task? Also, are there specific improvements we could make in terms of training strategy or hyperparameters to push this even further?
